# How to Extract zip File from jar file

Tags: java, jar, unzip

I am having a zip file into my project. When I am running my code through IDE, my `extract(String file, String destination)` method works fine.

```
 D:/Tools/JAVA/Lodable_Creation/build/classes/ib2.zip-->
 String s1=getClass().getResource("Test.zip").getPath().toString();
  extract(s1, "c:\\");
```

This is giving me Path  `s1 is--> D:\Tools\JAVA\Lodable_Creation\build`

When I compile same code and run through Command prompt

```
file:/D:/Tools/JAVA/Lodable_Creation/dist/Lodable_Creation.jar!/Test.zip
s1 is-->D:\Tools\JAVA\Lodable_Creation\dist
```

And I am not getting output. Please help me.

**UPDATE:-**

```
public static void extract(String file, String destination) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      // Open the ZIP file
      in = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
      // Get the first entry
      ZipEntry entry = null;
      while ((entry = in.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        String outFilename = entry.getName();
        // Open the output file
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
          new File(destination, outFilename).mkdirs();
        } else {
          out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination,outFilename));
          // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
          out.close();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      // Close the stream
      if (in != null) {
        in.close();
      }
      if (out != null) {
        out.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

**`On Ok Click button`**

```
Map map = System.getenv();
 Set keys = map.keySet();
 String newString  = (String) map.get("CYGWIN_HOME");
 System.out.println(" " + newString);
 String  destination= newString.replace(";", "");
 System.out.println(" " + destination);
 String S =getClass().getResource("Test.zip").getPath().toString();
 File jarFile = new File(S);
 String file=jarFile.toString();
 extract(file,destination);
```

This is my actual code for extract method and on **OK Button**. This is extracting Test.zip file to the Destination folder. i.e `CYGWIN_HOME`

Comment: I'm guessing that "Test.zip" is not found, probably because it's not in the proper location in your classpath.

Comment: Though looking deeper I wonder how anything works.  It doesn't seem like getResource on "Test.zip" could ever work.  I think you need to post your REAL code.

Comment: And the code of `extract()` is...?

Answer (score 0):

If your file path is actually a URL (starts with `"file://"`) then use `new ZipInputStream((new URL(file)).openStream())` otherwise use `new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))` like you already do.